# How to stop a metal table from vibrating when bumped

Tags: furniture, table, welding

I built this table recently and when you bump it, it vibrates continuously for several seconds. Imagine a tuning fork vibration, not a wobble. It makes everything on top of the table shake.

[image]

Does anyone have any ideas on what is causing this and what could be done to solve the problem? I just welded brackets in the corners and it did not fix the issue. I will try to post a photo of that as well. The steel tube legs are open on top and bottom. I tried with rubber feet and without. Tried on hard surface and carpet.

Answer (score 2):

I would guess that it's the long horizontal bars that are thrumming. Carefully drill one or more 1/4" holes on the inside of the tubing, where they're inconspicuous, and fill the tubes with sand or lead birdshot. Seal it up with tape or silicone.

To maintain strength in the bars, position the holes near connection points.

Comment: You can probably test the theory by holding the horizontal bars firmly with your hand while bumping the table, if the vibration is greatly reduced or eliminated, it go with this approach.